# PanelMatch R Errors: "please convert time id to consecutive integers" and "please convert unit id column to integer or numeric"

Tags: r, panel-data

When using the `PanelMatch` package in `R`, I'm getting a couple errors. Any guidance on how to resolve them would be greatly appreciated.

First, when running the `DisplayTreatment()` function, I get the following error: "please convert time id to consecutive integers". I've converted the time id to integer class with `as.integer(year)`, and I'm pretty sure they are consecutive---I've run `unique(year)` and can see that there are no gaps---but the error persists.

Second, when running the `PanelMatch()` function, I get this error: "please convert unit id column to integer or numeric". Again, I've tried converting the unit id to integer class, but the error persists.

The data can be downloaded here: [faads_women_09.dta.zip](https://github.com/insongkim/PanelMatch/files/10228442/faads_women_09.dta.zip). Here is the code necessary to replicate the issue:

```
house_ab <- read_dta("faads_women_09.dta")

house_ab$year <- as.integer(house_ab$year)
house_ab$statdistcons3 <- as.integer(house_ab$statdistcons3)

DisplayTreatment(unit.id = "statdistcons3", time.id = "year", legend.position = "none", xlab = "year", ylab = "CD", treatment = "female", data = house_ab)

PM.results.AB <- PanelMatch(lag = 4, time.id = "year", unit.id = "statdistcons3", treatment = "female",
                            refinement.method = "CBPS.match", data = house_ab, match.missing = TRUE, 
                            covs.formula = ~ party + unified_govt + terms + ln_statecapital + margin + ln_population + ln_age65 + ln_black + ln_constrct + ln_school + ln_farmer + ln_foreign + ln_manuf + ln_median_income + ln_unemployed + ln_miltpop + ln_urban,
                            size.match = 5, qoi = "att", outcome.var = "high_lnoutlays_cpi", forbid.treatment.reversal = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been vexed by the same problem for quite a while but finally figured it out. I looked up the error logic in the PanelMatch code

```
  if(!"data.frame" %in% class(data)) stop("please convert data to data.frame class")
  
  if(!class(data[, unit.id]) %in% c("integer", "numeric")) stop("please convert unit id column to integer or numeric")
  if(class(data[, time.id]) != "integer") stop("please convert time id to consecutive integers")
```

If we run `class(house_ab[,"year"]` we get:

```
"tbl_df"    "tbl"    "data.frame"
```

This means the data are stored as a [tibble](https://search.r-project.org/CRAN/refmans/tibble/html/tbl_df-class.html), rather than an ordinary (base) dataframe. Solution is to convert from a tibble to a base dataframe:

```
house_ab <- as.data.frame(house_ab)
DisplayTreatment(unit.id = "statdistcons3", time.id = "year", legend.position = "none", xlab = "year", ylab = "CD", treatment = "female", data = house_ab)

PM.results.AB <- PanelMatch(lag = 4, time.id = "year", unit.id = "statdistcons3", treatment = "female",
                            refinement.method = "CBPS.match", data = house_ab, match.missing = TRUE, 
                            covs.formula = ~ party + unified_govt + terms + ln_statecapital + margin + ln_population + ln_age65 + ln_black + ln_constrct + ln_school + ln_farmer + ln_foreign + ln_manuf + ln_median_income + ln_unemployed + ln_miltpop + ln_urban,
                            size.match = 5, qoi = "att", outcome.var = "high_lnoutlays_cpi", forbid.treatment.reversal = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 1):

Beyond coercing the data as a dataframe, you also need to use the `complete`function to complete the `statdistcons3` and `year` combinations. Below is the code:

```
house_ab <- house_ab %>% 
  complete(statdistcons3, year) %>% as.data.frame()
```

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is that the issue lies with the Stata version of the exported data. In your case, that would be 'faads_women_09.dta'. I encountered the same problem yesterday.

My solution to this problem was, firstly, to change the version to Version (12) in Stata, then load it in R. Secondly, I changed the unit id and time id to factors. With these changes, I was able to successfully generate the PanelMatch and DisplayTreatment commands. I hope this helps a bit.